# Field value in "<>" are not displayed in jQGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am working on to display JSON data into jQgrid . And able to displayed it properly . 
Able to display data when response like :

> {"page":"1","total":3,"records":"22","rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1","test
>   name","Owner1"]},{"id":"2","cell":["2","new test name","Owner2"]}]}

But having the issue when the name updated with the '<>' and jQgrid will not displayed the name and shows the empty name value

> {"page":"1","total":3,"records":"22","rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1","<test
>    name>","Owner1"]},{"id":"2","cell":["2","<new test name>","Owner2"]}]}

I have one way to do this that will replace this character at the time of fetching value from DB . But its not appropriate .

I am searching for the javascript or jQgrid function to display this name value or convert before load .

Let me know if you have any idea .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [autoencode: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option of jqGrid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to massage your data in any way before it gets inserted into the grid, try looking at the `beforeProcessing` [event](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents&s%5B%5D=beforeprocessing). That will let you loop through your returned data and clean it if you need to.